# How to enforce rate limiting for an IP that received 403 errors repeatedly in a Security Policy in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, throttling, rate-limiting, google-cloud-armor

I want to enforce rate limiting (throttling) if an IP has repeatedly faced 403 errors, on the edge, using Google Cloud Armor.

I have been able to enforce rate-based limiting/throttling for any IP that crosses the benchmark using the `enforceKey` on `IP` as the key.

However, I want to also throttle, at a higher priority, any IP that faces 403 errors.

Is this doable in Google Cloud Armor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not doable today as the 403 code is an origin response and Cloud Armor does not process outbound rules, just inbound.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Do you have a document link that I can reference? I did not know the answer, so I want to research this further.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview  "Google Cloud Armor security policies protect your application by providing Layer 7 filtering and by scrubbing incoming requests for common web attacks ..."

Comment: I have been following your answers and benefiting from your contributions. Thank you.